# What is the difference between CONTAINS and WITHIN on Elasticsearch GeoShape queries?

Tags: elasticsearch, geojson, elasticsearch-geo-shape

I try to determine if a polygon (indexed in document) has common point with another shape like a circle.

The Elasticsearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html) provides 4 types of relation:

- INTERSECT ;
- DISJOINCT ;
- CONTAINS ;
- WITHIN.

I try to find more information especially from the GeoJSON side without success.

I think the first type could answer my problem but I can't find the difference between the two lasts. The documentation is very short.

Thanks.

Comment: Typos: it's actually "INTERSECTS" and "DISJOINT". And case-insensitive BTW.

Comment: how can i use them at queries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`WITHIN` will return all documents whose `geo_shape` field **is within** the geometric shape specified in the query.

=> In this case, you will specify a geometric shape `A` in your query and ES will return all documents whose `geo_shape` field `B` is located entirely **WITHIN** that shape `A`: `A contains B`

`CONTAINS` will return all documents whose `geo_shape` field **contains** the geometric shape specified in the query.

=> In this case, ES will return all documents whose `geo_shape` field `B` **CONTAINS** the geometric shape `A` specified in your query: `B contains A`

Comment: I don't understand the grammatical difference. For me the both means inside something, English is not my primary language.

Comment: The difference is that `WITHIN` means `A contains B` and `CONTAINS` means `B contains A`, where `A` is the shape in the query and `B` is the shape in the documents.

Comment: I can explain in French, too ;)

Comment: Thanks you very much, I understood, basically it defines the direction of inclusion.